# sonar7.2.1 how to scan two specific languages

Tags: sonarqube

I tried in two ways，
1.I write properties file like sonar.language=php,go it didn't work.
2.I tried to change to sonar.languages=php,go and it scan all kinds of languages inculdes js,python and so on.
how can I make it to scan only specific several languages.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to configure `sonar.inclusions` and `sonar.exclusions` in a way that it will only include files you want to analyze. See documentation here https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus